# Problems with search feature in PHP

Tags: php

I have two table in db

```
bpi_registration
```

and

```
bpi_schoolInfo
```

The fields in bpi_registration are

```
id,id_school, first_name,last_name,city,state,email
```

and the fields in bpi_schoolInfo are

```
id_school,school_name,school_state
```

I am trying to create a search feature in such a way that whenever i select the name of school from dropdown the name of students with their information from that particular school show up. The URL looks like this when i select the name of school: `https://www.example.com/retrieve1.php?Grade=&School=kipp+spark+academy&Team=&Students=`

The code that i have written is:

```
if (isset($_GET['School']))
{

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM bpi_schoolInfo
    INNER JOIN bpi_registration ON bpi_registration.id_school = bpi_schoolInfo.id_school";

    $userQuery = "{$sql} WHERE bpi_schoolInfo.id_school = :school_id";
    $user = $db->prepare($userQuery);
    $user->execute(['school_id' => $_GET['School']]);
    $selectedUser=$user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(isset($selectedUser))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['first_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['last_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_city'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_state'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_country'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

However for some reason when i click on the name of school i am not able to see the list of students that are in that particular school. I am assuming i am doing something wrong with the queries and i would appreciate if someone can help me here.

Comment: Is 'kipp+spark+academy' the id or the school name? you may need to change your where statement to Where bpi_schoolInfo.id_school = :school_id to bpi_schoolInfo.school_name = :school_id. If this doesn't work can you provide a full create table for your two tables.

Comment: @Dbeazy kipp+spark+academy is school name and yes that solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET['School']` contains the school name, but you're comparing it with the school ID in your query. It should be:

```
    $userQuery = "{$sql} WHERE bpi_schoolInfo.school_name = :school_id";
```

Or you should change the URL to send the school ID instead of the name.